# `git clone` over HTTP Fails with "repository not found"

Tags: git, apache

I'm attempting to set up a publicly-accessible git repository that can be cloned via HTTP on a server that I physically own and have root access to, but it seems like I'm missing something. I'm new to git so I can't troubleshoot very well, but here's what I know:

1. I'm able to clone the git repository with `git clone ssh://git@repo.alaskawh.com/awhsome-framework` just fine
2. `git clone http://repo.alaskawh.com/framework` fails with `fatal: repository 'http://repo.alaskawh.com/framework/' not found`
3. http://repo.alaskawh.com/framework/ lists the file in the git repository just fine when I visit it in a web browser

`/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/awhsome-framework.git` is a symlink to `/var/www/repo.alaskawh.com/framework/`, I've created the file `hooks/post-update` which contains the line `exec git update-server-info`, and I've ensured that user permissions are correct.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you implemented a Git Smart HTTP server per [these docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP)?

Comment: @javabrett I didn't. I'm working on implementing it right now and it's doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set-up a [Git Smart HTTP server backend](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP).  Additional documentation is available [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend).  This will provide a simple and efficient Git hosting solution over HTTP.

Comment: The problem is definitely that I'm missing a Git Smart HTTP server backend; however, I haven't been able to get it to work properly yet. Also, I found [these instructions](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) to be more useful.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to add that link in the original answer but for some reason neglected to.  Edited/added.

Comment: I figured it out. The thing that I was missing was that value of `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` must be the directory above the directory containing the git files. For example, `GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` is set to `/var/www/repo.alaskawh.com/framework`, the actual git directory is located at `/var/www/repo.alaskawh.com/framework/awhsome-framework.git`, and then I can clone it with `git clone http://repo.alaskawh.com/framework/awhsome-framework`.