# `git clone` over "dumb" http protocol fails with `repository not found`

Tags: git

### My question

I'm trying to share a git repo on our company intranet server using the  [*dumb* http protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), which should only require file access, but it fails with

```
fatal: repository 'http://my-url/repo.git' not found
```

But pasting the same link in Firefox gives me the index to the *bare* repo with `branches/`, `config`, `description`, `HEAD` etc. All directories and files are readable.
In fact, if I download the whole thing recursively with wget I could `git clone` locally from that, so all required files seems accessible without issues.

```
$ wget -r --no-parent --reject "index.html*" http://my-url/repo.git
$ git clone repo.git test
Cloning into 'test'...
done.
```

Continuing the debugging I tried verbose output with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` and `GIT_TRACE`:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone http://my-url/repo.git test
trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'http://my-url/repo.git' 'test'
Cloning into 'test'...
trace: run_command: 'git-remote-http' 'origin' 'http://my-url/repo.git'
* Couldn't find host my-url in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to my-url port 80 (#0)
*   Trying <ip>...
* Connected to my-url (<ip>) port 80 (#0)
> GET /repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.8.3.1
Host: my-url
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 13:41:56 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red hat)
< shortcut-icon: /images/logo.ico
< Content-Length: 346
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< X-Cache: MISS from my-url
< 
* Connection #0 to host my-url left intact
fatal: repository 'http://my-host/repo.git/' not found
```

And to me it looks like it gives up after trying the "smart" http protocol. So, what's going on? From what I've been able to gather the dumb http protocol hasn't been dropped. Why does `git` give up after trying the smart http?

**Details**

- HTTP Server is Apache 2.2.15
- Anonymous read access via HTTP is allowed
- git version 1.8.3.1
- The repo is bare and is not symlinked
- `git update-server-info` has manually been called.
- I don't have access to the server and can't configure it, so the "smart http" option is out.
- The only thing in any (global, system, local) git-config is `user.name` and `user.email`.
- `env | grep GIT` is empty
- The results are the same for `https`.

*Edit:*
Updated with results for https (same)

---

### Similar questions

Similar question but without answers that are helpful in this case:
[Git Clone - Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947059/git-clone-repository-not-found)

Also similar, but the accepted answer uses "smart http" protocol.
[`git clone` over HTTP Fails with “repository not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313480/git-clone-over-http-fails-with-repository-not-found)

Comment: Can you verify that you have the files `info/refs` and `objects/info/packs` in the remote repo (i.e. trough Firefox)

Comment: I can check on Monday (I left for the weekend). But `git` doesn't even try to download those files, as shown by `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE`?

Comment: Yes, `info/refs` and `objects/info/packs` are there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: Manually provide option to disable "smart" http protocol:

```
$ GIT_SMART_HTTP=0 git clone http://my-dumb-http-server/repo.git
```

But according to
https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html:

> If the server does not respond with a Git HTTP smart service, the Git client will try to fall back to the simpler “dumb” HTTP protocol.

This does not seem to be the case for some reason. But after digging around in the code I saw that they check for `GIT_SMART_HTTP` environment variable and I got `git clone` working by setting `GIT_SMART_HTTP=0`.

Comment: Having the same issue I've found some context (i.e. why it works that way) http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/206096

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat The link leads to a "Not Found" page. Do you remember the subject, so it can be found again?

Answer (score 9):

It seems you have to run:

```
git update-server-info
```

Before the repo can be served via http.

You also need to switch on the post-update hook:

```
mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
```

This re-runs *git update-server-info* whenever new changes are pushed to the repo.

See the section on "Dumb http" here for more info:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: The the environment variable answer didn't apply to me for git client version `2.11.1`. This answer solved my cloning problem git server version `1.8.3.1`